# Configuring IIS with Powershell - Enable Forms Authentication

Tags: iis, powershell, web-config, forms-authentication

My IIS looks like this:

```
Sites ->
        Default Web Site ->
                            MyWebApp
```

Then the question is: How do I enable Forms Authentication on MyWebApp? I mange to change or edit Anonymous Access, Basic, and Windows Auth. However, Forms Auth is not that easy. How do I do this in Powershell?

I'm able to read the setting this way:

`(Get-WebConfiguration system.web/authentication 'IIS:\sites\Default Web Site\MyWebApp').Mode`

I'm having trouble or no luck with Set-Webconfiguration, or Set-Webconfigurationproperty. I find these cmdlets hard to figure out.

Change happens in web.config, at least the web.config updates when I hit Enable or Disable on Forms Authentication at the IIS manager. Any clues and tips are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You pipe the authentication configuration settings to Set-Webconfiguration giving the appropriate filter after you modify your properties:

```
$config = (Get-WebConfiguration system.web/authentication 'IIS:\sites\Default Web Site')
$config.mode = "Forms"
$config | Set-WebConfiguration system.web/authentication
```

**Note: Backup your config before trying this.**

Comment: Here's a more complete PowerShell IIS setup script that includes the same idea.  https://github.com/jefflomax/configure-iis-webapps-powershell

Comment: any idea how to also configure the SSL/Cookie settings?

Comment: @Rexovas - system.web/httpCookies

Answer (score 4):

Or with a one liner:

```
Set-WebConfiguration system.web/authentication 'IIS:\sites\Default Web Site' -value @{mode='Forms'}
```