# Pragmatically set IIS Setting in powershell

Tags: iis, powershell, web-applications

We have a project to set up a site's configuration with powershell. I need to know how to Set Anonymous Access to true and set the credentials to a domain user

I found a blog with  script example to get the current state from the web.config of the application 
[Blog click here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosag/archive/2008/02/11/microsoftwebadministrationinpowershell.aspx)

```
PS C:\ > $iis = new-object Microsoft.Web.Administration.ServerManager 
PS C:\ > $iis.Sites | foreach { 
$_.Applications | where { $_.ApplicationPoolName -eq 'DefaultAppPool' } | 
select-object Path,@{Name="AnonymousEnabled"; Expression = { 
$_.GetWebConfiguration().GetSection("system.webServer/security/authentication/anonymousAuthentication").GetAttributeValue("enabled") 
}} 
}
```

But if it is not set through web.config, how do i get it from the mroot config (machine.config?) and how do I modify the value to make sure it is set to true and set the username and password? any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: This post might help you out, follow the link given in @AUSTX_RJL 's comment on my answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13058537/configuring-iis-with-powerhsell-enable-forms-authentication/13058814#13058814

Comment: @Shay Levy's answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18136128/toggle-iis-7-5-authentication-anonymous-authentication-with-powershell-3-0 might help guide you as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much searching Found the answer this powershell function does what i require. I ended up using appcmd.

```
function SetAnonymousAccess
{
    Param 
    (       
        [String]$RelativePath,          #The Applications Relative Path
        [String]$SiteName,              #The Site the app is attached to
        [String]$EnableAnonymousAccess, #True or False to set AnonymousAccess 
        [String]$UserName,              #Username of anonymous Access
        [String]$Password               #Password of anonymous Access
    )

    if($RelativePath -notlike "[/]*"){$RelativePath = "/" + $RelativePath}
    $ConfAppName = $SiteName + $RelativePath
    $UserCredentials =""
    $msg = ""
    If($EnableAnonymousAccess -And $UserName -And $Password){
        $UserCredentials = "/userName:$UserName /password:$Password"
        $msg = "Applied AnonymousAccess=$EnableAnonymousAccess for user:$UserName"

    }else{
        $msg = "Applied AnonymousAccess=$EnableAnonymousAccess" 
    }   
    & $Env:WinDir\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config $ConfAppName /section:anonymousAuthentication $UserCredentials /enabled:$EnableAnonymousAccess  /commit:apphost
    Write-Host $msg -foregroundColor DarkGreen
}
```